# Differences in query logs when read by STH-Comet caused by Cygnus version upgrade

Tags: mongodb, fiware, fiware-cygnus, fiware-sth-comet

I am investigating Cygnus and STH-Comet and would like to know the impact of the Cygnus version upgrade.

I have created an environment with the following docker-compose.yml.
And, I have switched the Cygnus version in the commented out section to investigate.

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  orion:
    container_name: orion
    image: fiware/orion:3.7.0
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - "1026:1026"
    command: -dbhost mongo -logLevel DEBUG

  cygnus:
    container_name: cygnus
    image: fiware/cygnus-ngsi:2.20.0
    # image: fiware/cygnus-ngsi:3.2.0
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - "5051:5051"
      - "5080:5080"
    environment:
      - CYGNUS_MONGO_HOSTS=mongo:27017
      - CYGNUS_API_PORT=5080
      - CYGNUS_MONGO_DATA_MODEL=dm-by-service-path
      - CYGNUS_STH_DATA_MODEL=dm-by-service-path

  sth:
    container_name: sth
    image: fiware/sth-comet:2.10.0
    depends_on:
      - "mongo"
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - "8666:8666"
    environment:
      - STH_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - DB_URI=mongo:27017
      - DATA_MODEL=collection-per-service-path

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:4.4
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: --logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log --profile=1 --slowms=-1
```

I have created the following entities and also the following subscription.

entity:

```json
{
    "id": "Car1",
    "type": "Car",
    "speed": {
        "type": "Float",
        "value": 80,
        "metadata": {}
    }
}
```

subscription:

```json
{
  "description": "Test",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": "Car1$",
        "type": "Car"
      }
    ]
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://cygnus:5051/notify"
    },
    "attrsFormat": "legacy"
  },
  "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.000Z"
}
```

After creating the above subscription, I will update the entity several times to create historical data.

I ran the following command to get the historical data.

```bash
curl "localhost:8666/STH/v2/entities/Car1/attrs/speed?type=Car&lastN=5" -H 'fiware-service:example' -H 'fiware-servicepath:/'
```

The following query logs are mongodb logs when I read the historical data by STH-Comet.

```
// Log of STH-Comet query to get data written by Cygnus 2.20.0
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-28T03:54:01.910+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn11","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"sth_example.$cmd","command":{"listCollections":1,"filter":{"name":"sth_/"},"cursor":{},"nameOnly":true,"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"a7f6f881-1db3-42f0-86b6-c14fc3425419"}},"$db":"sth_example"},"numYields":0,"reslen":166,"locks":{"ParallelBatchWriterMode":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"FeatureCompatibilityVersion":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":2}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-28T03:54:01.916+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn11","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"sth_example.sth_/","command":{"count":"sth_/","query":{"entityId":"Car1","entityType":"Car","attrName":"speed"},"skip":0,"limit":0,"$db":"sth_example"},"planSummary":"COUNT_SCAN { entityId: 1, entityType: 1, attrName: 1, recvTime: 1 }","keysExamined":3,"docsExamined":0,"numYields":0,"queryHash":"41C2776D","planCacheKey":"2D54FA2D","reslen":45,"locks":{"FeatureCompatibilityVersion":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-28T03:54:01.920+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn11","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"sth_example.sth_/","command":{"find":"sth_/","filter":{"entityId":"Car1","entityType":"Car","attrName":"speed"},"sort":{"recvTime":-1},"limit":5,"returnKey":false,"showRecordId":false,"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"a7f6f881-1db3-42f0-86b6-c14fc3425419"}},"$db":"sth_example"},"planSummary":"IXSCAN { entityId: 1, entityType: 1, attrName: 1, recvTime: 1 }","keysExamined":2,"docsExamined":2,"cursorExhausted":true,"numYields":0,"nreturned":2,"queryHash":"C0A2C615","planCacheKey":"26B66C8B","reslen":380,"locks":{"FeatureCompatibilityVersion":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}

// Log of STH-Comet query to get data written by Cygnus 3.2.0
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-28T03:43:44.631+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn11","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"sth_example.$cmd","command":{"listCollections":1,"filter":{"name":"sth_/"},"cursor":{},"nameOnly":true,"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"8dde283d-302e-4374-aa83-a3c78a19080c"}},"$db":"sth_example"},"numYields":0,"reslen":166,"locks":{"ParallelBatchWriterMode":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"FeatureCompatibilityVersion":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":2}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-28T03:43:44.634+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn11","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"sth_example.sth_/","command":{"count":"sth_/","query":{"entityId":"Car1","entityType":"Car","attrName":"speed"},"skip":0,"limit":0,"$db":"sth_example"},"planSummary":"COLLSCAN","keysExamined":0,"docsExamined":2,"numYields":0,"queryHash":"41C2776D","planCacheKey":"2D54FA2D","reslen":45,"locks":{"FeatureCompatibilityVersion":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-28T03:43:44.636+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn11","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"sth_example.sth_/","command":{"find":"sth_/","filter":{"entityId":"Car1","entityType":"Car","attrName":"speed"},"sort":{"recvTime":-1},"limit":5,"returnKey":false,"showRecordId":false,"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"8dde283d-302e-4374-aa83-a3c78a19080c"}},"$db":"sth_example"},"planSummary":"IXSCAN { recvTime: 1, entityId: 1, entityType: 1, attrName: 1, attrType: 1, attrValue: 1 }","keysExamined":2,"docsExamined":2,"cursorExhausted":true,"numYields":0,"nreturned":2,"queryHash":"C0A2C615","planCacheKey":"26B66C8B","reslen":380,"locks":{"FeatureCompatibilityVersion":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
```

When I run the following code in STH-Comet, the "planSummary" goes from "COUNT_SCAN" to "COLLSCAN".

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet/blob/2.10.0/lib/database/sthDatabase.js#L510-L523

The more historical data, the slower that query becomes, is this a bug or am I misconfigured?

Thank you in advance.

The index of Cygnus 2.20.0 is shown below.

```json
> db['sth_/'].getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "entityId" : 1,
                        "entityType" : 1,
                        "attrName" : 1,
                        "recvTime" : 1
                },
                "name" : "cyg_raw_opt"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "recvTime" : 1
                },
                "name" : "cyg_raw_exp",
                "expireAfterSeconds" : NumberLong(1576800000)
        }
]
```

The index of Cygnus 3.2.0 is shown below.
However, the index of "entityId_1_entityType_1_attrName_1_recvTime_1" was added by me for improvement.

```json
rs0:PRIMARY> db['sth_/'].getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "entityId" : 1,
            "entityType" : 1,
            "attrName" : 1,
            "recvTime" : 1
        },
        "name" : "entityId_1_entityType_1_attrName_1_recvTime_1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "recvTime" : 1,
            "entityId" : 1,
            "entityType" : 1,
            "attrName" : 1,
            "attrType" : 1,
            "attrValue" : 1
        },
        "name" : "cyg_raw_opt"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "recvTime" : 1
        },
        "name" : "cyg_raw_exp",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : NumberLong(1576800000)
    }
]
```

Comment: I created an index referring to the following document.
https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet/blob/master/doc/manuals/db_indexes.md
The index was created and the query was executed counting by "COUNT_SCAN" from "COLLSCAN".
Please comment if you have any other information.

Comment: Just to check if I have understood the scenario correctly... When you use STH 2.10.0 and Cygnus 2.20.0 your query at STH uses COUNT_SCAN (good performance). When you use TSH 2.10.0 (i.e. same STH version) and Cygnus 3.2.0 your query at STH (exact same query than in the previous case) uses COLLSCAN (bad performance). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: By the way, although I don't think it has any impact in your use case, you shouldn't use `"attrsFormat": "legacy"` is your subscription (using that NGSIv1 notifications will be sent, and NGSIv1 is deprecated).

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your question to show how the indexes in the collections are in both cases (for the Cygnus 2.20.0 test and for the Cygnus 3.2.0 test). I mean, the output of the [getIndexes()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/) command.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for the delay on my response.
Your perception is correct.

Comment: I added the results of getIndexes() for each version.
The index of Cygnus 3.2.0 also shows the index I added.

Answer (score 1):

We have created [an issue at Cygnus repository](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/2291) to analyze this in detail and eventually provide a fix.

The workaround by the moment, according to @ctc-watanabe feedback, is to create manually this index:

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "entityId" : 1,
        "entityType" : 1,
        "attrName" : 1,
        "recvTime" : 1
    },
    "name" : "entityId_1_entityType_1_attrName_1_recvTime_1"
}
```